# Filling Excel cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pycharm, openpyxl

in my new department i have to code with python and openpyxl. I have to fill cells of an excel sheet with test runs and the result(passed/failed).
This is all i got so far. I am not getting any errors but the sheet is still empty.. Any help would be nice. Thanks in advance.

```
def create_report(self, root, now):
    tests = (
        ['Discover DTC time', 'failed'],
        ['Drucksensor_DTC_Startup', 'failed'],
        ['Drucksensor_DTC_Runtime', 'passed'],
    )

    wb = xl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = 'ExcelSummaryReport.xlsx'

    row = 1
    col = 0

    for i in range(row, ws.max_row):
        for j in range(col, ws.max_col):
            ws.cell(row=i + 1, col=j).value = tests[i]

    wb.save('ExcelSummaryReport.xlsx')
```

Comment: What does this have to do with pycharm?

Comment: the ide i'm using is pycharm

Comment: `ws.max_row` and `ws.max_col` really ought not be used like this.  Just loop over your test results and `ws.append()`

Comment: so how do i have to use ws.append()? how has the loop going to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new worksheet, it doesn't have any rows or columns, so `max_row` and `max_col` are 0, and your loop does nothing.  How many rows/columns to fill looks like it should be determined by the data (`tests`).

Comment: Yeah it will be determined by the data. But for the first step i want to fill this array in the sheet. the whole project will be more complicated.